# Why is Camfind API returning "image can't be blank" despite JPG attached with Request?

Tags: image, mashape, cloudsight

I just subscribed to Camfind API and am trying to upload an photo I took on my device using their Endpoint at https://www.mashape.com/imagesearcher/camfind#.

This endpoint lets you upload the image to be identified, along with other attributes (minimum required parameters are image_request[locale] and image_request[image] ).

My request had 3 parameters specified:

```
image_request[image]
image_request[locale]
image_request[language]
```

All other fields are optional and I left them blank.

Why does it keep thinking I haven't attached an image? Here is the reply I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 17:35:35 GMT
Server: Mashape/5.0.6
X-Cloudsight-Requestrate: 0.20389738512077885
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Ratelimit-Image-Requests-Limit: 500
X-Ratelimit-Image-Requests-Remaining: 498
X-Request-Id: fc2848a2-b7bc-4f25-b4d7-f5b5fe05ff1c
X-Runtime: 0.018830
X-Ua-Compatible: chrome=1
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
   "error": {
   "image": [
      "can't be blank"
]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include the original request you're making? preferably using curl, or code if possible. this will allow the community to help you debug this issue.

Comment: A common issue we see is that the image isn't part of a multi-part form encoded request when using the image_request[image] parameter (vs. the URL based parameter).  Can you post the code you're using to make the request?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of people experiencing the same issue and the common response from ImageSearcher is that Mashape has done some upgrades and this has affected their web interface. Recommendation is to log a ticket with Mashape. These posts were from over 6 months ago and nothing has changed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this . It is working

> {   "remote_image_url" :
>   "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg",
>   "locale" : "US-en",   "Authorization" : "CloudSight
>   jre10cooppia-Y_vfff", //your key   "language" : "US-en" }